# Screen dim after booting, need to suspend and resume to fix it

Tags: boot, grub2, brightness

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 and the screen is very dim on startup (even the manifacturer's splashscreen), and I need to suspend and resume it in orther to fix the issue. This has happened on 15.04 and 14.10 as well. I've tried adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`
 in /etc/default/grub  but it hasn't solved it.